# How to delete all Azure data factory pipeline and associated Dataflows, Datasets, Linked Services and Pipeline triggers from UAT environment

Tags: azure-devops, azure-data-factory, azure-deployment

I am performing Data Factory pipeline deployments from Development environment to UAT using ARM templates. I need to understand below situations while doing the deployment

1. After first time deployment, if I delete/update any data factory pipeline from/in development environment and then do the deployment into UAT, does the same pipeline gets deleted/updated automatically from/in UAT as well?
2. Is there any DevOps pipeline task which can delete all the ADF pipelines and associated datasets, dataflows, linked services and triggers from UAT before doing the next round of deployments from DEV to UAT?

Kindly provide me some clarification on these questions as I am doing this deployments first time.

Appreciate all the help!

Answer (score 0):

Before releasing a pipeline, the **pre and post deployment** script needs to be run.

Without this script, if we try to delete a pipeline in Data Factory and then try to deploy the current state in UAT then the **deletion** would not happen in UAT.

Refer this [Microsoft official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/continuous-integration-delivery-sample-script) for the pre and post deployment scripts for deletion of pipelines and other resources from the data factory.